# Is there a way to use external variable as choice parameters in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, deployment, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli, automated-deploy

I want to fetch data from my sql Table and use them as a choice parameters in Jenkins

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
| 11 |
| 23 |
| 45 |
| 72 |
|  5 |
| 16 |
| 71 |
| 18 |
+----+
```

I want to use these IDs as a choice parameter in Jenkins in order to build using one of these ID i.e. build with parameters using these ID numbers as Parameter

I simply want a drop down with these ID numbers as the choices before I build and the selected choice can be used as parameter to the script in the build step.

What would be the way of achieving this? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using **Extended Choice Parameters** in combination with a properties file.

1. Create a properties file with content `key=value1,value2,value3,...`, e.g., `key=11,23,45,72,5,16,71,18`.
2. Place this file in your Jenkins master filesystem, e.g., `/var/lib/jenkins/userContent/build.properties`. You need to write an automation script/create another job to update this file at regular intervals.
3. In your job configuration, select **This project is parameterized** > **Extended Choice Parameter**.
4. Enter a name for your parameter, e.g., `TABLE_VALUE`.
5. Select **Basic Parameter Type** > **Single Select**.
6. Enter the delimiter that you used to separate values in your properties file. In this case, the comma `,`.
7. Select **Property File** and enter the path to the properties file in Jenkins master - `/var/lib/jenkins/userContent/build.properties`.
8. Enter `key` as the **Property Key**.
9. Save the job configuration.
10. Access the value of the selected parameter using the variable `TABLE_VALUE` in your pipeline.

**Pipeline Code**

You can achieve the same in your pipeline by placing this block at the top:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        extendedChoice(
            name: 'TABLE_VALUE', 
            description: '', 
            type: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            multiSelectDelimiter: ',', 
            propertyFile: '/var/lib/jenkins/userContent/build.properties', 
            propertyKey: 'key',
            quoteValue: false
        )
    ])
])
```

See the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/extended-choice-parameter-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cwctravel/hudson/plugins/extended_choice_parameter/ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition.java#L344) for all possible parameters and [PT constants](https://github.com/jenkinsci/extended-choice-parameter-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cwctravel/hudson/plugins/extended_choice_parameter/ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition.java#L90) for all possible values of **type**.

**Job Configuration**

[image]

**Build Parameters**

[image]